# Smooth Scrolling between Table/Collection View and the Scroll View

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I am implementing a scroll view which consists of an image underneath it is a collection view.

What I want to do is a smooth scrolling between the page as if the collection view is just elements in the scroll view.
But what happens is the when I scroll, the collection view needs to be dragged twice to exit it or to enter it.

What I mean is that when the scroll view first appears there is an image and under it is collection view. when I scroll down if I touch the image, the scroll is done correctly, however, if I touch the view the image is still here and a small scroll is done then when I scroll again the scroll is done right and the collection view takes the whole screen
After that when I scroll upwards, the same happens a small scroll happens then I have to touch again to do the scroll right and show the image.

EDIT: This GIF shows would clarify what I mean : 
https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-75ed33ccd665.gif

Comment: Disable the scrolling of collectionview & add the height of collectionview, according to its content.

Comment: @MayurKarmur YEES !! It worked! .. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** The best solution was to create a TableView/CollectionView header and and my header in it and scroll normally for the table/collection view.

**Old solution**
The solution as provided in a comment by @MayurKarmur was to disable the scrolling in the collection view and adding height to collection view according to its content.